# Struggling with a 3D-array append

Tags: multidimensional-array, append

I want to merge several 2D-arrays into a 3D one, though I keep running into problems. This is my code so far:

```
AMv = 2
Bz = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8,7,6,5,4,3],[1,8,2,3,8,4,7,0,9,8],[3,6,2,3,4,5,7,8,8,7,8,7,8]]
PosVh = [2,5,9]

P = ['1', '2', '3']
MG = []
PMG = [][]

for a in range(0, len(P)):
 
    for b in range(0, AMv):

        MG.append(Bz[a][PosVh[b]:PosVh[b+1]])

        # print(MG)
    PMG[int(P[a])-1].append(MG)
    # print(MG)

print(MG)
```

I have the data array 'Bz', some of the data is sorted and rearranged according to 'PosVh'. The data is correctly sorted into the new array MG. What I want now is that for each Number in P there is a new row in PMG with the data of MG.
Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a solution that is almost what i want:

```
AMv = 2
Bz = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8,7,6,5,4,3],[1,8,2,3,8,4,7,0,9,8],    [3,6,2,3,4,5,7,8,8,7,8,7,8]]
PosVh = [2,5,9]

P = ['2', '1', '4']
MG = []
PMG = []

for a in range(0, len(P)):
     MG.append([])
     for b in range(0, AMv):

         MG[a].append(Bz[a][PosVh[b]:PosVh[b+1]])

print(MG)
```

The list appears to be alright. I just want to rearrange it like this:

```
MG[int(P[a])-1].append(Bz[a][PosVh[b]:PosVh[b+1]])
```

But if I do, the array turn out to be a [3][0] array. How can that be?